# How to use TraficStats API android

Tags: android

In android can we get `TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes()` date wise?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if you meant "data" wise or "date" as in chronologically. Either way, you'd call getTotalTxBytes at the beginning of wherever your code begins and store the value. To get the total amount of bytes transmitted since then, you'd call the function again and subtract the returned value from the previously stored value.

To monitor these values chronologically the method you would use varies greatly depending on implementation. For starters, you could store `System.currentTimeMillis()` when you're calling getTotalTxBytes.